# Bind engine to the notebook session

Tags: ipython

Is it possible to run notebook server with a kernel scheduled as processes on remote cluster (ssh or pbs), (with common directory on NFS)?

For example I have three servers with GPU and would like to run a notebook on one of them, but I do not like to start more than one notebook server. It would be ideal to have notebook server on 4th machine which would in some way scheduele kernels automatically or manually.

I did some trials with making cluster with one engine. Using %%px in each cell is almost a solution, but one cannot use introspection and the notebook code in fact is dependent on the cluster configuration which is not very good.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the notebook at this time.  The notebook cannot use a kernel that it did not start.

You could possibly write a new KernelManager that starts kernels remotely distributed across your machines and plug that into the notebook server, but you cannot attach an Engine or other existing kernel to the notebook server.

Comment: Considering multiuser feature which is planned in the roadmap - is such functionality considered? It would be very powerfull addition to %px capabilities - %px give one user access to big resources, while starting kernel from some hardware pool would give scalability of the notebook interface and access to some dedicated hardware like   GPU or Phi etc.

Comment: it has been discussed, but is not planned in the immediate future. Remote kernels can be done today with a subclasses KernelManager, but that's quite different from attaching to an already running kernel.